# How == operator works with System.Type

Tags: c#

```
typeof(int) == typeof(int)
```

How this expression evaluates ??

When i use

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int));
```

it outputs `System.Int32` using `ToString()` method of object. So i am assuming that in this expression

```
 typeof(int) == typeof(int)
```

`ToString()` converts both to `System.Int32` and then thier string gets compared. Is that true ??

Or something else happenning

Comment: Why do you think things have to be converted to strings before they're compared? You might want to consider the `Equals` method and the `Equality` operator that [`System.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) implements.

Comment: `int` is simply an alias of `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 3):

No. Like every other class usually does, it uses equality comparer (`==`) `System.Type` has overridden and the `Equals` method on one of the two instances to check their equality.

`typeof(int)` returns a `Type`, so `Type.Equals` is called. You can see the source [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs).

You will see it eventually uses this to compare the two instances:

```
return (Object.ReferenceEquals(this.UnderlyingSystemType, o.UnderlyingSystemType));
```

Comment: _"like every other class"_? Not every class [overrides the `==`-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The point is that if the class doesn't override the `Equality`-operator you get the reference equality check which often is not what you want.

Comment: Okay, I thought it used `object.Equals`, which would boil up to `Type.Equals`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I updated my answer according to your comments. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickHofman So you are saying System.Type is called finally and if type is same it returns true, false otherwise

Comment: @PatrickHofman i am still learning c#, so i didn't understand http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs 
what is here ??

Comment: Not finally, it is the only thing to call.

Comment: And the Reference Source, is the actual .source code of .NET 4.5.1, so you can take a look inside the code from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

The `typeof()` operator resolves to a `System.Type`, and the `==` operator on `System.Type` **checks reference equality**. This is enough for `System.Type`, because of this guarantee:

*A Type object that represents a type is unique; that is, two Type object references refer to the same object if and only if they represent the same type. This allows for comparison of Type objects using reference equality.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42892f65.aspx

So the answer is, the == checks whether the two types refer to the exact same object in memory, and if the original objects are of the same type, their types are guaranteed to refer to the same object in memory because of the above quote.

Answer (score 1):

The IL code for `typeof(int) == typeof(int)` is

```
IL_0000:  ldtoken     System.Int32
IL_0005:  call        System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle
IL_000A:  ldtoken     System.Int32
IL_000F:  call        System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle
IL_0014:  call        System.Type.op_Equality
```

You can see that it calls the static equality operator

```
public static bool operator ==(Type left, Type right)
```

We can't see what this method does in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs#1862) because apparently it's an external method, but my guess is it either calls the [`Equals`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/6ad282f6c8736636.html) method or performs a similar comparison in native code.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `Console.WriteLine(object);` prints out a `string` doesn't mean the `Type` type is *always* a string, similar to how you can print out an `int` value without said `int` being viewed and compared via its `ToString` method.

The `==` operator will test equality of the types, and in no way touches `ToString()`.

I think you're getting a bit confused--if I had to guess--on the differentiation between printing something and holding it in memory.